# Best practices for handling errors when opening files inside Swift classes?

Tags: swift

These two approaches work for opening a file inside a class and handling the possible error, with an implemented object that needs to persist outside of a try block:

```
class Thing1 {   
    var text: String = "" 

    init() {}    

    func load() throws {
        text = try String( contentsOfFile: "/Users/me/text.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding )
    }
}

let myThing1 = Thing1() // create an empty object

do {
    try myThing1.load() } // then load it with the file
catch let error as NSError {
    // do something with error
}
```

and

```
class Thing2 {   
    let text: String // text is loaded once, used only once
    var errorString: String?

    init() {      
        do {
            text = try String( contentsOfFile: "/Users/me/text.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding )
        } catch let error as NSError {
            errorString = error.description
            text = ""
        }
    }

    func error() -> String? {
        return errorString
    }  
}

let myThing2 = Thing2()

if myThing2.error() != nil {
    // do something with errorString = myThing2!.error()
}
```

From my days coding C++, the safer way was usually the first, but for an object that would persist outside of the try block, implementation requires that initialization would have to occur prior to loading the file. With optionals in Swift, the second approach becomes possible, with the added advantage that *text* is handled like the constant that it is. But then error handling is performed in a nonstandard class code-dependent way, and that would seem to be less safe.

I'm asking this question because all of my code using this class going forward will depend on this one design decision, I'm new to Swift, and I don't know how it works "under the hood". Any advice would be appreciated. Alternative approaches which I don't see due to my newness to Swift would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both forms. It depends on the context which is preferable.

For example if you're using the call in a function which throws an error anyway the throwing method is more convenient. If the error description is not important and you only want to check if the text is empty or not, the init method might be more suitable.

Comment: Really appreciate the heads-up on *nil* @vadian. Is the load() implementation in my code truly wrong? When I test it, it throws the error as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: You're right, this syntax is valid, too. I'll remove the first issue form the answer

Comment: your heads-up @vadian about returning nil made me realize that a failable initializer was entirely unnecessary in the example code for this question, so I removed it. Thanks! Can you expand on what you mean by "the context which is preferable"? That's exactly what I'm trying to understand with this question. Are there instances where, for example, memory costs would favor one approach or another?

Comment: It's not a question of memory or performance. I removes also the quoted documentation and added examples.